# Is there a way to give an Area an index view in MVC .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

As the question says I have areas in my site but I wanted to add a controller for the area itself.

Ex. `mysite.com/Area/Controller/` and `mysite.com/Area/`.

I havent found anything online that indicates how to do this.

Comment: Have you tried adding a `HomeController` with an index Action to the area? Or looked at how the area is registered?

Comment: So to your first suggestion, would that just give me the URL `mysite.com/Area/Home/`? And yea ive looked into the second suggestion but I think thats my problem, I dont know how to wire it up to get what I want.

Comment: After the first one did you try visiting `mysite.com/Area`. `Home` is probably the default controller and `Index` is also probably the default action.